# MKV to MP4 container solution

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, video-conversion, matroska

Right now I am using ffmpeg to convert from MKV to MP4 for my movies and tv shows. However This can only be done in one folder at a time or one move at a time as they are all in their own folder. I use this code:

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%%~na .mp4" pause
```

This works fine for instance if it's a tv show folder for a season and will go and convert each episode one at a time.

Is there a way to use batch to search the subfolders in the root directory ~1200 and find all MKV files, convert them to the new container retaining same audio/channels and then remove the old mkv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
FOR /R %%a etc etc
```

will recurse the sub-folders and adding "(" after the "DO" will allow you to enter more than one command over numerous lines. You then close the commands with ")"

I am not an expert at batch files by any means and the above was gleaned from http://ss64.com/nt/for.html ... I hope though this may be of some help

Comment: This indeed is working but it places each converter movie out into the root directory. I mean that isn't a huge deal but would prefer to stay in the folder. I found the code I'm using so not big on understanding the conversion process. So If there is a way to keep it in the same folder as well as remove the original mkv after conversion would be amazing.

Comment: I also get this all the time, it doesn't affect quality or conversion but curious about it.

Comment: [mp4 @ 00000000020c07a0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers
 is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp4 @ 00000000020c07a0] track 1: codec frame size is not set

Comment: Actually, transferring to the root is fine, would there be a way to just delete the original folder said movie is in. Then I won't have to go back through everything to remove dups and then can also use filebot for renaming.

Comment: I do see adding this to the end del "%%~a"

Comment: This may work but I think it will just remove original file.
for /R %%a in ("*.mkv") do (
 ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%%~na .mp4" 
 del "%%~a"
)
pause

Just tried this and happened to cancel the process and removed about 15 movies completely that are unrecoverable so this si one fun process lol

Comment: One fun process indeed @cyris69 - if you can capture the directory the file is stored in, then following conversion, you could use RD /Q to delete the directory. **NOTE** suggest you set up a test directory away from valuable files to play with this... using  set Var=%CD% captures the **current** directory to %%Var%%

Comment: Good deal, I'll give that a try as well. Last night I forget I had Remove Empty Directories program installed and was using that for the time being. I also noticed since I didn't trust this running while I couldn't watch it that if I did ctrl c to use as a pause (choice of terminating or  not the batch job using y/n) that it would still remove the just started next or current movie even if I attempted to resume.